# How to constraint a container with other widget? Adjusting Height to its Parent in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: need container to take up height of the view list]
[image: expected behavior]

```
Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              ViewListPanel(widget.vehicleDetails, onNavigationClick,
                                  widget.vehicleDetailsList),
                          
                              InkWell(
                                onTap: () {
                                  widget.setListView(widget.index);
                                  /*
                                          setState(() {
                                            mVehicleList![index].isSwipe = !vehicleList![index].isSwipe!;
                                          });*/
                                },
                                child: IntrinsicHeight(
                                  child: Container(
                                      width: screenWidth! * 0.06,
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        color: AppTheme.appColors,
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                          topRight: Radius.circular(0),
                                          bottomRight: Radius.circular(5),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      child: Icon(Icons.more_vert_outlined, color: Colors.white)),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
```

I want to constraint the container to top and bottom of viewListPanel here ViewListPanel is a set of text widgets
**ViewListPanel***

```
return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          getWidgets(
            "Distance Covered",
            '${double.parse(vehicleDetails!.currentInfo!.odoMeter!).toInt()} km',
            DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(DateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss")
                .parse(vehicleDetails!.currentInfo!.lastTimeStamp!, true)),
            DateFormat("hh:mm:ss aaa").format(DateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss")
                .parse(vehicleDetails!.currentInfo!.lastTimeStamp!, true)),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: screenHeight! * 0.5 / 100,
          ),
          getWidgets(
              "Distance to Empty",
              '${getDTEValue()} km',
              'Battery Status',
              '${vehicleDetails!.currentInfo!.socStatus} %'),
           SizedBox(
            height: screenHeight! * 0.3 / 100,
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                width: (screenWidth! * 55) / 100,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "Location",
                      style: labelStyle,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: 20),
                    InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        showDialog(
                          context: context,
                          builder: (BuildContext context) {
                            return AlertDialog(
                              title: Text(
                                "Location",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: "NotoSansMedium",
                                  fontSize: 18,
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                ),
                              ),
                              content: Text(
                                '${vehicleDetails!.currentInfo!.currentLocation}',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontFamily: "NotoSansBold",
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    color: Colors.black),
                              ),
                              actions: <Widget>[
                                TextButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                  },
                                  child: Text(
                                    "Close",
                                    style: TextStyle(color: AppTheme.appColors),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            );
                          },
                        );
                      },
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.info,
                        size: 20,
                        color: AppTheme.appColors,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Vehicle Status',
                    style: labelStyle,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                  // SizedBox(height: screenHeight! * 0.2 / 100),
                  Text(
                    vehicleDetails!.currentInfo!.vehStatus.toString(),
                    style: bottomLabel,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
          /*getWidgets('Last Location', '', 'Charging Status',
              vehicleDetails!.currentInfo!.vehStatus.toString()),*/
        ],
      ),
    );
```

How to constraint a container height to its parent? I want the height to be dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to use `IntrinsicHeight` but it needs to be outside the row to work with the row's children and also you need to tell the row the `CrossAxisAlignment` to stretch:

```
IntrinsicHeight(
  child: Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,  
    children: [
      ViewListPanel(widget.vehicleDetails, onNavigationClick,
          widget.vehicleDetailsList),    
      InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          widget.setListView(widget.index);
          /*
                  setState(() {
                    mVehicleList![index].isSwipe = !vehicleList![index].isSwipe!;
                  });*/
        },
      child: Container(
          width: screenWidth! * 0.06,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: AppTheme.appColors,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topRight: Radius.circular(0),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(5),
            ),
          ),
          child: Icon(Icons.more_vert_outlined, color: Colors.white)),
        ),         
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```